# Read only combobox?

Tags: c#

How do I make a combobox read only? I remember back when I used VS2005 you could have a read only combobox in the default style. Reason I **don't** want to use **DropDownList** is because it looks ugly on forms that don't use a default color. Here is an example.

[image]

I want one like in the left of this picture.

[image]

Were you can not enter in your own text. But I don't want the style in the first image to the right.

Comment: Are you saying you want to have an editable combo box in which only items in the list portion are selectable (or accepted in edit mode)?

Comment: I want one like the debug/release combobox on VS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the drop down style to `DropDownList` and the flatStyle to `Flat`:

```
this.ComboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
this.comboBox1.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
```

You can select always the `element[0]` (if exists) to look like the example you provided.

The Visual Studio combo draws a border OnMouseHover, you can also do this if you want.

Comment: The background is still gray.

Comment: @High: Ok, I see. The VS designer shows it with the background grey. Close the designer and open it again and you'll see the background correctly. Anyway this is a designer issue (maybe an Invalidate() is missing in the FlatStyle setter). In runtime all works fine.

Comment: O okay, thankyou. Ya I have been having issues with the designer bugging out lately when I am making non standard GUIs. Would WPF help at all?

Answer (score 2):

Change the drop down style, it's a property.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownstyle.aspx

Comment: None of the dropdown styles give me what I want.